# How to write a.dbf file

Tags: r, merge, append, dbf

I'm encountering issue using the below script. All are working fine except for the final line which results to the error below.

[image]

```
# read dbf
library(foreign)
setwd("C:/Users/JGGliban/Desktop/Work/ADMIN/Other Stream/PH")

# Combine multiple dbf files
# library('tidyverse')
# List all files ending with dbf in directory
dbf_files <- list.files(pattern = c("*.DBF","*.dbf"), full.names = TRUE)
# Read each dbf file into a list
dbf_list <- lapply(dbf_files, read.dbf, as.is = FALSE)
# Concatenate the data in each dbf file into one combined data frame
data <- do.call(rbind, dbf_list)
# Write dbf file - max-nchar is the maimum number of characters allowed in a character field. After the max, it will be truncated.
x <- write.dbf(data, file, factor2char = TRUE, max_nchar = 254)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code modified to:

```
x <- write.dbf(data, "file.dbf", factor2char = TRUE, max_nchar = 254)
```